# Data defined label alignment option greyed out on new Quantum GIS Dufour

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am trying to customise the positioning of labels in relation to points in a vector file layer in the new QGIS 2.0.

In QGIS 1.8 I was able to enter two customised X/Y columns in the attribute table of a shapefile to precisely align the labels around the points.

However, from the new QGIS 2.0 menu 'Layer label options'>'Placement'>'Data defined', the X and Y 'Alignment' options are greyed out and I am unable to enter the columns.

Please see a screen dump of the issue below

Can anybody explain why this might be the case? Thanks for your consideration.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include some more information related to the layers that you have loaded in, and the type of layer that you are trying to add labels for.  As it is now, there is not enough context for what may be causing these options to be greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Coordinate X and Y binding to enable the Alignment binding.

[image]